# Custom messages are not generated in ROS 2

Tags: cmake, ros-humble, lidar, custom-message, package.xml

##### Project Goal

I am working on a project with ROS 2 where my primary goal is to read data from LVX files (associated with Livox LiDAR sensors) and publish this data to a ROS bag. The key steps in my project include:

1. Reading LVX Files: Implementing a Python script or a ROS node to parse LVX files and extract the necessary data.
2. Defining Custom Messages: Creating custom ROS messages suitable for the data extracted from LVX files. I have already started with a message named DeviceInfo.msg but anticipate needing more for different data types in the LVX file.
3. Publishing Data: Using a ROS publisher to send the parsed data to a ROS topic, using the defined custom messages.
4. Recording to ROS Bag: Utilizing ros2 bag record to save the published data for later analysis and use.
5. Timestamps: Ensuring accurate timestamping for the data to maintain consistency and reliability in the ROS ecosystem.

##### Current Status and Issue:

I've begun setting up my ROS 2 package (`livox_2_rosbag`) and defining the necessary custom messages. However, I am encountering an issue where the Python files for my custom messages are not being generated in the site-packages directory, though they are present in the share directory.

Below is the content of DeviceInfo.msg

```
string lidar_sn_code
string hub_sn_code
uint8 device_index
uint8 device_type
bool extrinsic_enable
float32 roll
float32 pitch
float32 yaw
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
```

Below is the content of Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd"  schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>livox_2_rosbag</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="veneela@todo.todo">veneela</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>
  <depend>builtin_interfaces</depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <build_depend>ament_cmake</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rclpy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>tf2</depend>
  <depend>tf2_ros</depend>
  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Below is the content of CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(livox_2_rosbag)

# Find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(builtin_interfaces REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_runtime REQUIRED)

# Generate custom messages
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/DeviceInfo.msg"
  # Add other message or service files here
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs builtin_interfaces
)

# Install Python modules
ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install Python executables
install(PROGRAMS
  livox_2_rosbag/livox_reader.py
  # List other Python scripts here
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# Install directories like launch and config
install(
  DIRECTORY launch config
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

# Setup the project
ament_package()
```

##### Questions

1. How can I resolve the issue with the custom message Python files not being generated in the expected directory?
2. Are there any best practices or considerations I should be aware of for my project's goals, particularly regarding reading from LVX files and publishing to ROS bags?

##### Environment

- ROS 2 Distribution: Humble
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (CODENALE: jammy)
- Python Version: 3.10.12

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 

The question contains lots of unnecessary details. It is good practice to keep the question concise. Most of the time, sharing a[Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps a lot. Anyway, I could not replicate your issue. However, I was able to compile your `DeviceInfo.msg`. It seems your CMakeList.txt file is missing `ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)`. Please see an example [here](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/tree/humble).